# Responsiveness problem when going to production [Next JS, tailwind]

Tags: next.js, mobile, tailwind-css, responsive, production

I have build my portfolio website with 4 projects to be able to apply for internships and entry-level front-end positions using Next.js and tailwind css and for the portfolio webpage and the dashboard project it becomes unresponsive when going to production by vercel.Especially for the sidebar in the portfolio page in mobile screen sizes and for the weather page the api doesn't work in production but all work in development? how to fix that? why is this all happening? is it something that happens during the building phase in Next.js?

P.S. I use Next.js 13.5 pages router

Here's the site : https://portfolio1-ten-lime.vercel.app

Here's the repo: https://github.com/Alharith-Albayati/portfolio.git

I appreciate your help attempts :)